# Resolving view from ajax request using spring 3

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

Jquery code to call my spring controller:

```
$.postJSON("/DialogController", myJSON, function(data) {
  previewDialog.html(data);
  previewDialog.dialog('open');
});
```

And then my controller code, which causes a `http 500 error`, I have debugged it and find it all works fine until the return string(view name), what am I doing wrong ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/DialogController", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String dialogController(Model model, @RequestBody MyClass myClass) {
  myClass.setTitle("SUCCESS");       
  model.addAttribute("myClass", myClass);
  return "dialogContent";
}
```

Using jquery load with get request on the controller works to an extent - in that it returns the view and loads into dialog; but the attribute is not added to model and I can not post json data to the controller.

Any tips ?

Comment: What do your logs say?  If you get a 500 error, you'll get a useful bunch of log entries telling you what you did wrong.  Without seeing that, noone else can help you.

Comment: @skaffman that implies you think it should work ?  The logs have nothing useful in them, just that the request has been made. I have stepped through the controller using a debugger and it all works except for the final return string. This is the normal method for returning a view - I have set up to use interalviewresolver and prefix/append the correct filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting @ResponseBody in your Controller? More information on this annotation is here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody